# How to sort an array of objects based on another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have these arrays:

Array 1:

```
const arr1 = [
  {_id: "13", qtde: 1, color: "red", size: "100x100"},
  {_id: "16", qtde: 5, color: "green", size: "200x200"},
  {_id: "1", qtde: 3, color: "yellow", size: "300x300"},
  {_id: "23", qtde: 2, color: "purple", size: "500x500"},
  {_id: "3", qtde: 0, color: "orange", size: "200x200"}
]
```

Array 2:

```
const arr2 = [
  {_id: "23", name: "Produto-23", price: "48.99"},
  {_id: "13", name: "Produto-13", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "3", name: "Produto-3", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "1", name: "Produto-1", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "16", name: "Produto-16", price: "58.99"}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
const arr2 = [
  {_id: "13", name: "Produto-13", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "16", name: "Produto-16", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "1", name: "Produto-1", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "23", name: "Produto-23", price: "48.99"},
  {_id: "3", name: "Produto-3", price: "58.99"}
]
```

As can be seen they are different but they have the property `_id` in common, but not in the same order. What I want to do is reorganize the second array to have the same order as the first one based on its property `_id`.

Just to be clear, I don't want to merge the arrays or change anything besides the order of the second one.

I thought about using `Array.sort`, but since I don't have a property of reference I don't know how it could be applied here. The basic idea is to use the index of the first array as reference, since it won't change, but I don't know how as well.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) in the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as follows:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {_id: "13", qtde: 1, color: "red", size: "100x100"},
  {_id: "16", qtde: 5, color: "green", size: "200x200"},
  {_id: "1", qtde: 3, color: "yellow", size: "300x300"},
  {_id: "23", qtde: 2, color: "purple", size: "500x500"},
  {_id: "3", qtde: 0, color: "orange", size: "200x200"}
]
const arr2 = [
  {_id: "23", name: "Produto-23", price: "48.99"},
  {_id: "13", name: "Produto-13", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "3", name: "Produto-3", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "1", name: "Produto-1", price: "58.99"},
  {_id: "16", name: "Produto-16", price: "58.99"}
]

const arr2Sorted = arr2.sort((a,b) => {
  const indexOfA = arr1.findIndex(e => e._id === a._id);
  const indexOfB = arr1.findIndex(e => e._id === b._id);
  return indexOfA - indexOfB;
});

console.log(arr2Sorted);
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a lookup map from the first array and then sort the other array with the lookup map.

```js
const createLookup = (arr, key) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, curr, index) =>
    ({ ...acc, [curr[key]]: index }), {});

const sortWithLookup = (arr, key, lookup) =>
  arr.sort((a, b) => lookup[a[key]] - lookup[b[key]]);

const arr1 = [
  { _id: "13", qtde: 1, color: "red",    size: "100x100" },
  { _id: "16", qtde: 5, color: "green",  size: "200x200" },
  { _id:  "1", qtde: 3, color: "yellow", size: "300x300" },
  { _id: "23", qtde: 2, color: "purple", size: "500x500" },
  { _id:  "3", qtde: 0, color: "orange", size: "200x200" }
];

const arr2 = [
  { _id: "23", name: "Produto-23", price: "48.99" },
  { _id: "13", name: "Produto-13", price: "58.99" },
  { _id:  "3", name: "Produto-3",  price: "58.99" },
  { _id:  "1", name: "Produto-1",  price: "58.99" },
  { _id: "16", name: "Produto-16", price: "58.99" }
];

const lookup = createLookup(arr1, '_id');
const sorted = sortWithLookup(arr2, '_id', lookup);

sorted.forEach(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```